# How to change the druid admin default password?

Tags: apache-superset, druid

In Druid I am using default basic authenticator

**My config look like this**

```
druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator"]
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.type=basic
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword=password1
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.initialInternalClientPassword=password2
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.credentialsValidator.type=metadata
```

If I change admin password from password1 to another. it is not reflecting on druid console!
It gives an error!

So how to change admin password in Druid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has been previously created and you change the initialAdminPassword property it will have no affect as it is stored in the metadata.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html#properties-for-druid-metadata-store-user-authentication

You should be able to send a POST to the coordinator leader with the initial admin:password1 to change the admin password. Make sure to save it somewhere as I have been unable to recover lost passwords.

```
curl -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --user admin:password1 <coordinator_leader_ip:port>/druid-ext/basic-security/authentication/db/{authenticatorName}/users/{userName}/credentials --data '{ "password": "newPassword2" }'
```

In your case:

{authenticatorName} = basic

{userName} = admin

<coordinator_leader_ip:port> is often times http://localhost:8081/ if you have mounted the coordinator

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html#usercredential-management